# Home dirs when changing UI locale

Tags: locale

I was doing some changes in a custom Trusty multilanguage distribution I realized at work and I was thinking about UI locale changing.

I try to better explain: my distro comes in 18 preinstalled languages with the goal to be distributed by our PR office on a USB key on which both syslinux.cfg and splash.png are customized (syslinux is configured not to show Install/Try choice and I've removed "quiet splash" directive too); when an user starts it for the first time, it comes in english with english keyboard.

Change UI locale in Ubuntu is not so difficult but neither so easy, mostly for administrative managers (to whom PR gives USB keys), so I've added a little script opening a html document with every explanation, a sort of little howto.

I was thinking about a script using zenity that allows user to change UI locale operating on ~/.profile file but every time I run it, moving from a locale to another and I answer "yes" to the question asking if I want to rename home subdirectories, when I try to open Desktop from "Places" menu, in some languages (like oc_FR, for example) it fails because of the way the word "Desktop" is translated and sometimes it keeps the old language name, while in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs the name is unique and correctly written: it seems that "places" menu doesn't read ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs at least for what is concerning Desktop directory. And the same things happens if I change UI locale from System Tools --> Preferences --> Language Settings.
Anyone can help me?

And another question (that bypasses the previous, if I can find a solution): Is there a way to select UI interface before logging in? I mean: in Linux Mint, suppressing autologin file, I can obligate the user to write his/her username and password (that's empty, anyway) and in login mask user can choose his/her UI locale; is there such a solution in Trusty?

Thanks,

Silvia

Comment: Is it a Kubuntu system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility may be to keep the English folder names for all users, and prevent the prompt about renaming them from showing up. I think that can be done by removing the file `~/.config/user-dirs.locale`.

The login manager lightdm-gtk-greeter allows you to select the display language at login. However, if we are talking about a Kubuntu system, I'm not sure whether lightdm-gtk-greeter is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gunnar!
I didn't think about changing greeter; this way it works perfectly. I didn't try - for the moment - to remove  ~/.config/user-dirs.locale : I'll think about because 99 times on 100 users won't change language so maybe is better letting system to rename home directories. And maybe I'll modify syslinux.cfg/isolinux.cfg to let user choose her/his language before boot.

Silvia